# Code to delete rows containing a search string skips some rows with the string

Tags: excel, vba

I have written some code in Excel VBA below, which deletes rows based on user input. It almost completely works but in some cases leaves one or two instances of the search string in the data.

```
Dim SrchStr As String

'enter email address to be searched

SrchStr = InputBox("Enter email")

'open each file and if email address is found, delete that row and save workbook

Workbooks.Open File1
Dim Cell As Variant
Dim SrchRng As Range
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each Cell In SrchRng
    If Cell.Value = SrchStr Then
        Cell.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next Cell

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: First rule of deleting rows: Always delete from the bottom, up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Dim SrchStr As String

'enter email address to be searched

SrchStr = InputBox("Enter email")

'open each file and if email address is found, delete that row and save workbook

Workbooks.Open File1
Dim Cell As Variant
Dim SrchRng As range
Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

lastIndex = SrchRng.Rows.Count

For i = lastIndex To 1 Step -1
    For Each Cell In SrchRng.Rows(i).Cells
        If Cell.Value = SrchStr Then
            Cell.EntireRow.Delete
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
Next

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You need to delete from the bottom, up. This is because when you delete a row, the rows below shift up, meaning the 'next' cell it needs to check will be on the same row, not the next. Working from end to start gets around this neatly.

```
Dim i as Long
With SrchRng
    For i = .Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(i).Value = SrchStr Then
        .Cells(i).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next 
End With
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Completely makes sense - learnt something new today.

Comment: If you're happy with one or more of the answers here, don't forget to mark your favourite as the answer.